# How to complete a stream of numbers as CSV values in Akka HTTP?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I have a Akka source as a stream of numbers implemented as:

```
Source(Stream(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

I am trying make use of Akka streaming support in Akka HTTP to return a streaming response as **comma-separated values**.

I have followed [akka doc](https://docs.huihoo.com/akka/akka-http/10.0.7/scala/http/routing-dsl/source-streaming-support.html#simple-csv-streaming-example) on simple csv source streaming to come up with the following implementation:

```
implicit val csvFormat = Marshaller.strict[Int, ByteString] { res =>
    Marshalling.WithFixedContentType(ContentTypes.`text/csv(UTF-8)`, () => {
    ByteString(List(res).mkString(","))
    })
}

implicit val streamingSupport: CsvEntityStreamingSupport = EntityStreamingSupport.csv()

complete(Source(Stream(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)))
```

But apparently this is not the right use case of CSV entity streaming support for my purpose. This results in every number being streamed in a new line.

But that is not what I want. I want to reply as comma-separated list instead, like `1,2,3,4,5`.

How is it possible to achieve this using streaming support in Akka HTTP?

Comment: that's not valid content for content type of `text/csv(UTF-8)` - https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180#section-2 . Can you state your requirement in very simple words without adding any implementation details?

Comment: Object `akka.http.scaladsl.model.ContentType` defines this as a valid val.

Comment: In simple words, I need to stream a list of numbers as a comma-separated values and not new-line separated.

Comment: Since you are just streaming the individual integers... its actually a `text/plain` response.

Comment: Changing it to `text/plain` results in `curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That newline is added by the flow-renderer defined in `EntityStreamingSupport.csv()`.

We need to define our own custom `EntityStreamingSupport` for this to work.

```scala
val route =
  path("test") {
    val responseSource: Source[Int, NotUsed] =
      Source.fromIterator(() => Stream(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).iterator)

    val byteStringSource: Source[ByteString, NotUsed] =
      responseSource.map(i => ByteString(i.toString))

    val streamingSource =
      byteStringSource.map(bs => HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`, bs))

    implicit val streamingSupport =
      EntityStreamingSupport.csv(maxLineLength = 16 * 1024)
        .withSupported(ContentTypeRange(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`))
        .withContentType(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`)
        .withFramingRenderer(Flow[ByteString].map(bs => bs ++ ByteString(",")))

    complete((streamingSource))
  }
```

```
curl localhost:8080/test -v 
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /test HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: akka-http/10.2.4
< Date: Tue, 20 Jul 2021 07:50:46 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
1,2,3,4,5,* Closing connection 0
```

Edit : to elimiate that traling comma, we can use a window hack.

```scala
val route =
  path("test") {
    val responseSource: Source[Int, NotUsed] =
      Source.fromIterator(() => Stream(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).iterator)

    val startByteString = ByteString("$start$")

    val byteStringSource: Source[ByteString, NotUsed] =
        responseSource.map(i => ByteString(i.toString)).prepend(Source.single(startByteString))

    val streamingSource =
      byteStringSource.map(bs => HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`, bs))

    implicit val streamingSupport =
      EntityStreamingSupport.csv(maxLineLength = 16 * 1024)
        .withSupported(ContentTypeRange(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`))
        .withContentType(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`)
        .withFramingRenderer(
          Flow[ByteString].sliding(2, 1)
            .map { bsSeq =>
              if (startByteString.equals(bsSeq(0))) {
                // first int; no need for comma
                bsSeq(1)
              } else {
                // not first int; add comma
                ByteString(",") ++ bsSeq(1)
              }

            }
        )

    complete((streamingSource))
  }
```

```
curl localhost:8080/test -v 
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /test HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: akka-http/10.2.4
< Date: Tue, 20 Jul 2021 08:28:05 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
1,2,3,4,5* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: Thanks @sarveshseri. This seems to work fine! Only thing I am worried if this will work for a stream of infinite numbers since you have specified `maxLineLength = 16 * 1024`?

Comment: I don't think that http is really the right medium for "infinite" streaming. There are a lot of settings which will terminate the request at a certain point. You should use web-sockets for that.

Comment: Seems like it breaks off with message `curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining` and then continues with the rest of the streaming.

Comment: Had it not been the requirement to present a comma-separated stream of numbers. The solution I presented in the question should work fine for infinite stream of numbers, right? And same would apply for SSE, right?

Comment: No. There are a lot of "limiters" (like timeout, max-content-length etc) applied on http request in all server implementations, you can tweak the limiters but can not remove them. And it is never advisable to have "near infinite" http requests in production.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a higher-level class. It can't be an Int and compose a row with more than one column. Creating such a class as the following `MyBO` does the trick.

```
    case class MyBO(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int, e: Int)
    
    implicit val myBOAsCsv = Marshaller.strict[MyBO, ByteString] { t =>
      Marshalling.WithFixedContentType(ContentTypes.`text/csv(UTF-8)`, () => {
        ByteString(List(t.a, t.b, t.c, t.d, t.e).mkString(","))
        })
      }

    implicit val csvStreaming = EntityStreamingSupport.csv()

    val route: Route =
      path("ping") {
        get {
          complete(Source(Stream(MyBO(1,3,5,7,11))))
        }
      }
```

```
 curl localhost:8080/ping -v                                                                                                                               [3f8df8e]
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /ping HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: akka-http/10.2.4
< Date: Tue, 20 Jul 2021 07:10:18 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8
<
1,3,5,7,11
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer! But I think I didn't put my problem statement across very clearly. Apologies for that. The idea is to be able to stream an infinite stream of numbers. I don't this using case classes would help.

Comment: No problem :). Happy to see you've got your answer